# Type Class for Related Types

Tags: scala

Let's say we have the following traits:

```
trait MyValue
object MyValue {
  case class MyBoolean(record: Boolean) extends MyValue
  case class MyLong(record: Long) extends MyValue
}

trait MyValueExtractor[T] {
  def apply(record: T): Option[MyValue]
}

trait MyThing[T] {
  def name: String
  def myValueExtractor: MyValueExtractor[T]
  def myValue(record: T): Option[MyValue] = myValueExtractor(record)
}
```

What I want is something like this **but without the second type parameter.**
*Note: I can't actually update the `MyThing` trait; I'm just using this as an illustration of the intended functionality.*

```
trait MyThing[T, U] {
  def name: String
  def myValueExtractor: MyValueExtractor[T]
  def myValue(record: T): Option[MyValue] = myValueExtractor(record)
  def myRelatedValue(record: T): Option[U]
}
```

I'm wondering if I could use the type class pattern to help solve this (i.e., import some rich class that implicitly gives me a `myRelatedValue` method)?

Here's the rub. **Every time** `T` (above) is `MyValue.MyBoolean`, `U` must be a `String`. Every time `T` is `MyValue.MyLong`, `U` must be a `Double`. In other words, there's a sort of underlying mapping between `T` and `U`.

Is there a good way to do this using type class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure. You just need to define some `Mapping` typeclass with implementations for your desired pairs of types. Then `MyThing` can have a method that takes an implicit typeclass instance and simply invokes its method.

Here's the code (I removed the unneeded details)

```
// types

case class MyBoolean(record: Boolean)
case class MyLong(record: Long)

// trait which uses the Mapping typeclass

trait MyThing[T] {
    def myRelatedValue[U](record: T)(implicit ev: Mapping[T, U]): Option[U] = ev.relatedValue(record)
}

// typeclass itself

trait Mapping[T, U] {
    def relatedValue(record: T): Option[U]
}

object Mapping {
    implicit val boolStringMapping = new Mapping[MyBoolean, String] {
        def relatedValue(record: MyBoolean) = Some(record.record.toString)
    }
    implicit val longDoubleMapping = new Mapping[MyLong, Double] {
        def relatedValue(record: MyLong) = Some(record.record)
    }
}

// usage

val myBoolThing = new MyThing[MyBoolean] {}
val myLongThing = new MyThing[MyLong] {}
val myStringThing = new MyThing[String] {}

myBoolThing.myRelatedValue(MyBoolean(true)) // Some(true)
myLongThing.myRelatedValue(MyLong(42L))     // Some(42.0)
myStringThing.myRelatedValue("someString")  // error: could not find implicit value
```

Note that e.g. `myBoolThing.myRelatedValue(MyBoolean(true))` will yield a type `Option[U]`. However, since `myRelatedValue` is parameterized, you can help the compiler and invoke it as `myBoolThing.myRelatedValue[String](MyBoolean(true))`, in which case you will obtain an `Option[String]`. If you try something other than String for MyBoolean, you will get an error.

Comment: I think you could make it even nicer with `Aux` and `trait Mapping[T] { type U }` so implicit resolution happens only on the first generic and you can't have duplicate instances for the same source type.

Comment: Quick follow-up if that's ok :) Because this relies on implicit ev within the `MyThing` trait, if I try to call `myRelatedValue` without importing the `Mapping` into scope, I'll get a compiler error, right? Wondering if that's a good reason to separate this functionality as an implicit class that is only available if you import the implicits? (It sort of makes clear that you get the `myRelatedValue` functionality only if you import this.) Or, is there a way to somehow define these implicits in `MyThing` so it's always in scope?

Comment: @user451151 I think I didn't really get the question. But if you're asking what's going to happen to users of `MyThing` if they don't import the Mapping, answer is - they are going to be fine. Compiler will search for implicits in the `Mapping` companion object and find them there. But if users wants to add some new combinations, e.g. [MyInt, Int], then they have to provide their own implicits for that.

Comment: Ahh, shoot -- I made a mistake in my question. I'll post a new one. This was still very useful, thank you!

Comment: Just in case you're still interested :)  I updated with a new question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45527679/implicit-evidence-from-a-type-within-a-trait