# Implicit evidence from a type within a trait

Tags: scala

Let's say we have the following:

```
object MyValue {
  case class MyBoolean(record: Boolean) extends MyValue
  case class MyDouble(record: Double) extends MyValue
}

trait MyValue
```

and a sealed trait:

```
object MyValueGrabber {
  trait MyBooleanGrabber[T] extends MyValueGrabber[T] {
    override def apply(record: T): Option[MyValue.MyBoolean]
  }

  trait MyDoubleGrabber[T] extends MyValueGrabber[T] {
    override def apply(record: T): Option[MyValue.MyDouble]
  }
}

sealed trait MyValueGrabber[T] {
  def apply(record: T): Option[MyValue]
}
```

as well as a mapping between the `MyValue` type and a different type with which it is associated:

```
object Mapper {
  implicit val myBooleanMapper = new Mapper[MyValueGrabber.MyBooleanGrabber[_], String] {
    override def getValue: String = "found a bool"
  }

  implicit val myDoubleMapper = new Mapper[MyValueGrabber.MyDoubleGrabber[_], Long] {
    override def getValue: Long = 100L
  }
}

trait Mapper[A, B] {
  def getValue: B
}
```

and then we have:

```
trait HolyGrail[T] {
  def name: String
  def myValueGrabber: MyValueGrabber[T]
  def getValue[U] = ???
}
```

The question is how do we use the `Mapper` implicitly to return the correct type `U`. Ideally, it would be something like:

```
def getValue[U](implicit ev: Mapper[myValueGrabber.type, U]) = ev.getValue  // doesn't work
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use it like this:

```
def getValue[U](implicit ev: Mapper[MyValueGrabber[T], U]) = ev.getValue
```

As methods do not have `.type`. (Their converted function have, but I think that is not what you want.)

Based on the clarifications in the comments, I think you want something like Shapeless' [HMap](https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless/wiki/Feature-overview:-shapeless-2.0.0#heterogenous-maps).

You will probably need to adjust your `ValueGrabber` trait a bit:

```
sealed trait MyValueGrabber[T, -R <: MyValue] {
  def apply(record: T): Option[R]
}
```

or

```
sealed trait MyValueGrabber[T] {
  type R <: MyValue
  def apply(record: T): Option[R]
}
```

probably the latter is harder to use in your `getValue`:

```
def getValue[U, O](implicit ev: Mapper[MyValueGrabber[T] {type R = O}, U]): U = ev.getValue
```

the former would look like this (but as I understand not what you want):

```
trait HolyGrail[T, R] {
  def name: String
  def myValueGrabber: MyValueGrabber[T, R]
  def getValue[U](implicit ev: Mapper[MyValueGrabber[T, R], U]): U = ev.getValue
}
```

I do not know how to do the thing you want (path dependent type with trait) without shapeless.

Comment: Apologies, I made a type-o in the original post. I have corrected it now. I need to match on something like MyValueGrabber[_] (independent of its type parameter).

Comment: I guess you still miss something in your question because I do not see anything which would make it problematic with my proposed solution (though I do not fully understand your use case, I hope you do :) ). All things in `Mapper` are irrelevant in `HolyGrail` and `myValueGrabber.type` just does not make sense  (at compile time you cannot evaluate or refer to the runtime result type of a method, just an other parameter's compile time type).

Comment: Your solution makes the implicit ev dependent on `T`, which means that for every type `T`, I'd need to explicitly declare an implicit val to act as evidence. I want to only provide two implicit vals: one for `MyBooleanGrabber[_]` and one for `MyDoubleGrabber[_]` (independent of `T`. Does that make sense? Thanks in advance for your help!  :)

Comment: Maybe a better way to state it is: If `myValueGrabber` within the `HolyGrail` trait is a `MyValueGrabber.MyBooleanGrabber`, I always want to return a `String` in `getValue`, irrespective of what the type param `T` is. Similarly, if it is a `MyValueGrabber.MyDoubleGrabber`, I want to return a `Long`.

Comment: I have updated a bit, but probably not what you want. I would check Shapeless' HMap for similar usecases or add `myValueGrabber` as an implicit parameter of `getValue` (or just make it implicit), but I think that is not what you want.